# What is Scala's Comparable trait?

Tags: scala, comparable, traits

I am searching for Scala counterpart of C# IComparable, and I found Comparable trait. I mean -- Comparable is mentioned, but when I search for it at http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/ I get 0 hits. Because of the name, using Google I get a lot of "how Scala is comparable to..." results.

Is there any resource I could read about this mysterious Comparable thing? After all Ordered extends it, so it has to exist.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `Comparable` that you saw mentioned must have been `java.lang.Comparable`. There is no trait named `Comparable` in Scala stdlib. Scala's `Ordered` trait extends `java.lang.Comparable`.

Comment: Thank you. In such case I consider Ordered info quite misleading, it says "trait Ordered [A] extends Comparable[A]", see: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Ordered.html

Comment: @macias And if you keep the mouse over "Ordered" to see where's from, you'll see a hint box popping up with "java.lang.Comparable". Also, if it were from Scala, it would be a link -- though that's just a deficiency in Scaladoc, as we'd like for it to link to Javadoc.